# Build SOAP XML Web Service that stores data to DB and response result to client

Tags: java, sql, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been assigned to build SOAP XML web service which does the following:

1. Listens for a SOAP request from client application that will send the values for 2 parameter(login name, product_id)
2. Stores the SOAP request/outbound response transaction to a SQL database table
3. Doing checking if login already exist or not in database. if yes, send response to client. If not, the values store in database and also response back to client

I am planning to do this JAVA.
Can anybody point me in the right direction for how this should be done? Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Comment: What platform do you want to use? Spring, JEE? Any Application Server you are forced to use? (No one is using Application Servers of their own will)

Answer (score 1):

To build a SOAP XML web service you need web service provider and web service client. To do so there are two approaches:

1. Top Down

Top down is the proper way of defining rules for the web service for both client and provider. Top down means you have to create a WSDL file first in order to generate stubs out of it to create provider as well as client.

2. Bottom UP

Bottom is used for legacy application, to expose already existing application as a web service

Wsdl to java is a plugin used to generate stubs(classes) out of wsdl file. After creating wsdl and stubs out of it...you need to mark the pojo's with JAX-B Annotations and service methods(Your web service business logic methods) with JAX-WS Annotations. For this you could use Apache CXF JAX-WS Maven Dependency or others. After that you need to publish an Endpoint for the web service you created using bus and Endpoint class from JAX-WS.

After Exposing out the service, you can use the same wsdl to generate Client or Without creating a client you could test your web service using SOAP UI tool.

Follow this [Link](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html) for more!